# Lightdm Login Loop - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04, login, intel-graphics, lightdm

Recently, my Nvidia video card failed (Hardware Failure) on me. I uninstalled the drivers and updated `mesa-utils` (after proper Nvidia cleanup) , added `linux-generic` and tried to login. No matter what i do , i am unable to login via `lightdm` - my system is bit old with Integrated Intel Graphics.

I also did `purge lightdm` , deleted its user, cleaned the system. reboot, reinstalled `lightdm` , checked `.Xauthority` access etc.

Comment: Please clarify what the Nvidia card 'failing' is referring to. Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightDM as of now is buggy and is honestly no longer recommended past 14-04. To fix this boot into Grub recovery mode, **ENABLE NETWORKING,** Then drop to root shell.

`sudo apt-get install gdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

Then you can most likely reboot and Ubuntu will boot correctly.

`sudo shutdown now -r`

Hope this helped. If it did, make sure to vote up and check it so others with this problem can see this.

Comment: Thanks. It did allowed me to atleast see the desktop, but other problems arised. so i ditched unity and installed cinnamon with gdm. It is working a ok now.